# Exception caught by image resource service ═ Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting above exception on console even though I handled the error

```
child: CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl: "Invaild url to create error",
                    width: 300,
                    height: 300,
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    errorWidget: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                      return Container(
                        width: 300,
                        height: 300,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[errorWidget property](https://pub.dev/documentation/cached_network_image/latest/cached_network_image/CachedNetworkImage/errorWidget.html) will only be used when the target image URL failed to load, for example due to a 404 NotFound exception. If your URL is null, you should probably create another widget to handle this.

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to do that

Comment: click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.